# How to access components of the 256 bit ps vector

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics, avx

How to efficiently access the elements of the 256-bit vector? For example I calculated the dot product with

```
c = _mm256_dp_ps(a, b, 0xff);
```

How to access the value in c then? I need to get both high part and low part, do I understand correctly that I first need to extract 128 bit parts like this:

```
r0 = _mm256_extractf128_ps(c,0);
r1 = _mm256_extractf128_ps(c,1);
```

And only then extract floats:

```
_MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT(fr0, r0, 0);
_MM_EXTRACT_FLOAT(fr1, r1, 0);

return fr0 + fr1;
```

Comment: If you're doing that much packing/unpacking just for a single dot-product, then you might want to consider redesigning the relevant code to keep such data movement to a minimum.

Comment: Suggestions are welcome. I need to calculate dot product for vectors of 16 floats. AVX route seems the best choice for me but I'm not happy with the code indeed.

Comment: Are each of the vectors contiguous in memory?

Comment: Yes, they are even 32-byte aligned

Comment: This is tricky because that dot-product instruction is kinda weird. The alternative is to vector multiply them and then do a binary reducing tree of additions.

Comment: Ok, it appeared that _mm256_extractf128_ps is ok to use and compiler just optimizes it into just VZEROUPPER and returns xmm0 but I decided to give up with AVX and use SSE4. This appeared to be more convenient with medium size vectors and way faster than mm256_dp_ps on 256 bits. mm256_dp_ps is really slow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no efficient way to do this. dp_ps operation itself is slow and subsequent extraction is slow. Unless one can process more data in a batch it's faster to use SSE4 instructions to calculate dot product and operate with 128 bits than with 256 bits.

Comment: You only asked how to do this, not how to do it fast :)  I have posted some code example to do batch dot products as well, and that will be faster, maybe faster than SSE4.  Also, two different ways to get result of single dot product.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you could just store to memory and then work with scalars:

```
float v[8];
*(__m256)(v) = _mm256_dp_ps(a, b, 0xff);
float result = v[0] + v[4];
```

You could also swap the top to the bottom half of the 256-bit register and add, like this:

```
__m256 c = _mm256_dp_ps(a, b, 0xff);
__m256 d = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(c, c, 1);
__m256 result = _mm256_add_ps(c, d);
```

Likely much faster than either option is to do 4x 8-wide dot products at a time and reduce them together.  A sketch:

```
d0 = _mm256_dp_ps(a[0], b[0], 0xff);
d1 = _mm256_dp_ps(a[1], b[1], 0xff);
d2 = _mm256_dp_ps(a[2], b[2], 0xff);
d3 = _mm256_dp_ps(a[3], b[3], 0xff);

d01 = _mm256_permute_ps(d0, d1, ...);
d23 = _mm256_permute_ps(d2, d3, ...);
d0123 = _mm256_permute_ps(d01, d23, ...);

d0123upper = _mm256_permute2f128_ps(d0123, d0123, 1);
d = _mm256_add_ps(d0123upper, d0123); // lower 128 bits contain the results of 4 8-wide dot products
```

Comment: Didn't understand the faster option, how can you permute these: d01 = _mm256_permute_ps(d0, d1, ...);  The method revecives only one register

Comment: @Shahar If d0 contains floats d0.0, d0.1 to d0.8, and d1 contains d1.0, d1.1 to d1.8, etc, d0123 should contain d0.0, d1.0, d2.0, d3.0, d0.4, d1.4, d2.4, d3.4.  I know the intrinsics I mentioned don't quite do that, but it needs to be some kinds of permutation... suggestions welcome ;)